# Referencing the result of a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, rdbms

I am working on a stored procedure that needs to compare two values. Here is my sql code

```
SELECT customer_id, max_rentals
FROM accounting inner join rental_plans
ON accounting.rental_plan_id = rental_plans.rental_plan_id
WHERE customer_id = 0
```

this returns:

```
customer_id max_rentals
----------- -----------
0           3
```

I want to write a statement that says if the value of max rentals for customer 0 is 3 then do something. How do I reference that value in my conditional statement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "do something"?

Comment: Here's what I want to do...

Check to see if the value of max rentals @ customer id = 1 is 3. If it is then add 25 to their account balance

Answer (score 1):

Will this work as you expected?

```
UPDATE <table>
SET <update field>=<value>
WHERE <table>.Customer_id IN (
    SELECT customer_id
    FROM accounting inner join rental_plans
    ON accounting.rental_plan_id = rental_plans.rental_plan_id
    WHERE max_rentals=3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to achieve something like this.

Using case statement you can check if max_rentals = 3 then do something.

```
SELECT customer_id, max_rentals,
case   when max_rentals=3 then 'do something' else max_rentals end
FROM   accounting inner join rental_plans
ON     accounting.rental_plan_id = rental_plans.rental_plan_id
WHERE  customer_id = 0;
```

Comment: but how do I check if max rentals for customer_id = 3?

Comment: @LuisBarahona in where clause like this `WHERE customer_id = 3;`

Comment: Does this look correct?

IF 
accounting.movies_out > 0 Where customer_id = @customer_id THEN